# Title: "Undeclared attribute type error for enum 'screen_location' after Rails upgrade from 7.0.1 to 7.1.2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

After upgrading my Rails application from version 7.0.1 to 7.1.2, I'm encountering an issue with an enum attribute named 'screen_location.' The error message states, "Undeclared attribute type for enum 'screen_location.' Enums must be backed by a database column or declared with an explicit type via attribute." It's worth noting that I haven't made any changes in the database, and this issue has surfaced post-upgrade. How can I resolve this enum-related error without modifying the database schema in Rails 7.1.2?

explicit attribute didn't work for me and i want to resolve this issue without making any changes to schema

Comment: Can you post the actual code that is causing this and the class that declares the `screen_location` enum?

Comment: enum screen_location: {
    "home_tier_1" => 1,
    "home_tier_2" => 2,
    "store_tier_1" => 3,
    "store_tier_2" => 4
}

Comment: Please post the code in the question. Also can you confirm that you have met what the error is showing? e.g. the `screen_location` attribute is backed by a column in the database or explicitly declared as an attribute. See Here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/45668 and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/49717 and https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45734 for more details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a database column, it is necessary to define an attribute using the attribute method, mirroring the name. Following the example in the 7.1.2 changelog, **the attribute must be specified as type :string:**

Reinstate the capability to use enums with non-column-backed attributes. For attributes lacking a corresponding column, their types must be explicitly declared. For instance:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :topic, :string
  enum topic: %i[science tech engineering math]
end
```

Incorporate this approach into your code:

```
attribute :status_ids, :string
attribute :type_ids, :string

enum status_ids: { ... }
enum type_ids: { ... }
```

It's important to note that without a corresponding database column, these attributes will not be stored persistently and will not be accessible for database queries.